# Embed javascript in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

How to embed java-script in the java code written in gwt.Please give me an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here's some doc to help you get started

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html

here's a simple example of a native method:

```
private native void nativeMethod()
/*-{
      $wnd.jsFunction = function(x) {
        alert(x);
      };
      alert("hello");
}-*/;
```

it creates a javascript function called `jsFunction` that can be called from HTML or any other javascript. and then it alerts.

Comment: Hey,dldnh thanks for your answer however can u give me a simple example to implement it in an EntryPoint class?

Comment: sure, it's a bit contrived, but perhaps it will help with syntax as well as the notion that you can access the main window as `$wnd` to create functions and do other things.